# jQuery UI autocomplete with mysql database

Tags: mysql, jquery-ui, autocomplete

i'm struggling with jQuery autocomplete whole day. I cannot figure out how to connect jQuery UI autocomplete with mysql database. I don't know what should php file look like, how's request sent to php etc.. In demos and documentation on jQuery site there is simple example with remote datasource where source is: source: "search.php". So how search.php knows what i've typed in input box? there is no query attached to search.php :/ I've noticed that json is used.. i'm confused and i've tried dozen method without results. What i need is simple autocomplete with name of cities that contains text i've typed into textbox.

My db looks like:

```
table_cities:
-------------
id:   -city id
name: -city name
```

And i need autocomplete to show me cities that contains text i've typed into textbox e.g.

"po" will result in "liverpool" "Portsmouth"...

```
html
----
<input type="text" id="cities" />

js
--
$( "#cities" ).autocomplete({
...
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to return a JSON-encoded array of id/value objects. The autocomplete plugin also sends over a get parameter named "q" which contains what is currently in the input box. A simple example of a `search.php` file that would work:

```
$autocomplete_value = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET["q"]);
$sql = "select id, name from table_cities where name LIKE '%$autocomplete_value%'";
$query = mysql_query($sql);

$results = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    array_push($results, array('id' => $row['id'], 
                               'value' => $row['name']) );
}
echo json_encode($results);
```

You'll need to adapt that to whatever PHP framework you might be using, but the pattern should be the same - loop through the results creating an array of 'id' and 'value' objects, then json encoding that.

Edit: you might want to update the SQL to do lowercase compare (so capitalization is ignored) and other such enhancements, but this should at least get you going in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks, this solved half of problem, i didn't know that request is sent over parameter named "q". Other half of problem is jQuery.. When i used your php code with simple jquery, return was all cities, not just matching cities:                                 $( "#cities" ).autocomplete({
  source: "scripts/loc.php",
  minLength: 4,
  select: function( event, ui ) {
  alert(ui.item.id);
  }
});

Comment: Look into Firebug for Firefox or use Safari/Chrome's built in development mode - great for debugging the ajax calls and see what is being sent to/from the server.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used jQuery autocomplete, but it seems clear that it makes an AJAX call back to your web server, providing the data that has already been typed in the box.  The web server will query the database as you see fit, and return the results that should be displayed.

The query would not be part of the jQuery plugin; you would have to write that yourself.

Comment: Yes, i saw that on some examples there is ajax used ($.ajax..) but i don't understand how it's working in that example on jQuery UI demos and documentation -> remote datasource. When you click to view source for that example there is only source: ""search.php" without $.ajax..

Comment: I would imagine `search.php` accepts a form value; when the php file is invoked, it grabs the form value, queries the database, and returns a result set to the caller (in this case the plugin) which would then display the results.  Which part of this are you having difficulty with?

Answer (score -1):

You can use ".=" in while loop.

```
$data = "";
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
$data .= "bla bla bla..."
}
```